# dynamic image to data return duplicate id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote a script to upload image, with convert image to data (base64). with this user can select multiple images, you can select one image or at least three image, all together or separately. for each image it append a new div called `.image-uploader` contains `input:hidden` and `preview` and each items has unique `id` like `image-1-val` `image-2-val` or etc.

With `var n = i + 1;` create dynamic `id`.

**The Problem:**

Now the problem is if user select one image, then select second image then or more.. dynamic id not working as expected, it made duplicate id, such `image-1-val` again `image-1-val` .. Note that, but if user select more than one image all together, for example two or three images on one select, it work fine.

**Question:**

How can I set dynamic `id` if user just select one single image, then add another one? Can I detect if `id` exist then prevent to make duplicate `id` ?

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vgrk1rmz/8/)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply count current `.image-uploader` length, you already have this:

```
var imglength = $('.image-uploader').length;
```

So plus `imglength` with `i`:

```
var n = i + imglength + 1;
```

**[Live Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/vgrk1rmz/15/)**